# GDAL warp and translate on EASE-2 crossing the IDL

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I have some GeoTIFF data defined on an EASE-2 grid that I would like to convert into a PNG image using the WebMercator projection. `gdalwarp` does the job quite well except for a few files that cross the International Date Line.

**Context**

I use a recent version of GDAL (3.4.0) on a Linux workstation (ArchLinux).

My first attempts all resulted in images with the correct pixels on the left side of the IDL and nothing on the right side.

[image: image produced with default proj defintions]

```
gdalwarp -overwrite \
         -of PNG \
         -r bilinear \
         -s_srs '+proj=cea +lat_ts=30 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs' \
         -t_srs '+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +over' \
         -te 18478437.56426216 -3526567.7566842334 22079470.891229756 -471745.1255075845 \
         -tr 24834.712599776532 24835.95635102967 \
         -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=100 \
         -wo SAMPLE_GRID=YES \
         input.tiff warped.png
```

After struggling quite a bit, I found out that I had to append `+over` to the source SRS definition so that coordinates outside the projection domain would not be discarded. It allowed me to get the full reprojected image:

[image: image produced with +over in source proj defintion]

So I thought I had a working solution, but...

**The real problem**

This operation must be included in an existing processing chain which requires GeoTIFF files to be warped in VRT format and then translated into PNG, so I simply changed the output format and added a `gdal_translate` step to check that everything would work fine:

```
# Warp to VRT
gdalwarp -overwrite \
         -of VRT \
         -r bilinear \
         -s_srs '+proj=cea +lat_ts=30 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +over' \
         -t_srs '+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +over' \
         -te 18478437.56426216 -3526567.7566842334 22079470.891229756 -471745.1255075845 \
         -tr 24834.712599776532 24835.95635102967 \
         -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=100 \
         -wo SAMPLE_GRID=YES \
         input.tiff warped.vrt

# Translate to PNG
gdal_translate -of png warped.vrt warped_translated.png
```

And now I get the same result as before:

[image: image produced by translating the VRT]

The VRT file looks like this (I removed the color table entries because it is quite verbose):

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="145" rasterYSize="123" subClass="VRTWarpedDataset">
  <SRS dataAxisToSRSAxisMapping="1,2">PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199
433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Nor
thing",NORTH],EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs +over"]]</SRS>
  <GeoTransform>  1.8478437564262159e+07,  2.4834712599776532e+04,  0.0000000000000000e+00, -4.7174512550758448e+05,  0.0000000000000000e+00, -2.4835956351029668e+04</GeoTransform>
  <Metadata>
    <MDI key="AREA_OR_POINT">Area</MDI>
  </Metadata>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1" subClass="VRTWarpedRasterBand">
    <NoDataValue>255</NoDataValue>
    <Scale>0.1968503892421722</Scale>
    <ColorInterp>Palette</ColorInterp>
    <ColorTable>
     [...]
    </ColorTable>
  </VRTRasterBand>
  <BlockXSize>145</BlockXSize>
  <BlockYSize>123</BlockYSize>
  <GDALWarpOptions>
    <WarpMemoryLimit>6.71089e+07</WarpMemoryLimit>
    <ResampleAlg>Bilinear</ResampleAlg>
    <WorkingDataType>Byte</WorkingDataType>
    <Option name="SOURCE_EXTRA">100</Option>
    <Option name="SAMPLE_GRID">YES</Option>
    <Option name="INIT_DEST">NO_DATA</Option>
    <Option name="ERROR_OUT_IF_EMPTY_SOURCE_WINDOW">FALSE</Option>
    <SourceDataset relativeToVRT="1">input.tiff</SourceDataset>
    <Transformer>
      <ApproxTransformer>
        <MaxError>0.125</MaxError>
        <BaseTransformer>
          <GenImgProjTransformer>
            <SrcGeoTransform>16016204.2847920042,24969.5940102417953,0,-3678604.30822801823,0,24912.30206970172</SrcGeoTransform>
            <SrcInvGeoTransform>-641.428301886791814,4.00487088252147509e-05,0,147.66215895808071,0,4.01408106405468478e-05</SrcInvGeoTransform>
            <DstGeoTransform>18478437.5642621592,24834.7125997765324,0,-471745.125507584482,0,-24835.9563510296684</DstGeoTransform>
            <DstInvGeoTransform>-744.056831341323118,4.02662199525110763e-05,0,-18.994441721509407,0,-4.02642034744331976e-05</DstInvGeoTransform>
            <ReprojectTransformer>
              <ReprojectionTransformer>
                <SourceSRS>PROJCS["unknown",GEOGCS["unknown",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]]],PROJECTION["Cylindrical_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",30],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=cea +lat_ts=30 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +over"]]</SourceSRS>
                <TargetSRS>PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs +over"]]</TargetSRS>
              </ReprojectionTransformer>
            </ReprojectTransformer>
          </GenImgProjTransformer>
        </BaseTransformer>
      </ApproxTransformer>
    </Transformer>
    <BandList>
      <BandMapping src="1" dst="1">
        <SrcNoDataReal>255</SrcNoDataReal>
        <SrcNoDataImag>0</SrcNoDataImag>
        <DstNoDataReal>255</DstNoDataReal>
        <DstNoDataImag>0</DstNoDataImag>
      </BandMapping>
    </BandList>
  </GDALWarpOptions>
</VRTDataset>
```

The `+over` that I added in the definition of the source projection is still there in the `<ReprojectionTransformer><SourceSRS>` element so I would expect `gdal_translate` to "see" the full data as the projection issues have been handled in the VRT.

I am not very knowledgeable about GDAL so I am not sure why I get different results when using `gdalwarp` with a PNG output and when using `gdalwarp` with VRT output followed by `gdal_translate` with PNG output.

Does anyone understand what is going on and know how I could fix this issue?